# SwitchyOmega: Using a different "Proxy Profile" for an existing "Switch Profile"

Tags: proxy

I have Switch profile with many rules

```
[SwitchyOmega Conditions]
@with result

*.forbidden-domain.com +hola
...
...
...

* +direct
```

instead of using `hola` profile I'd like to be able to use all those rules to use another proxy  profile.

Of course I'd like to avoid duplicating the profile manually and keep the 2 profiles in sync.

it's probably possible create a custom *PAC Script*, but I don't know what would be the syntax to interact with existing SwitchyOmega profiles.